# Implementing bitwise XNOR

Tags: java, c, algorithm

I saw a question for finding non repeatitive number from the set that contains only one distict number and rest numberes can be repeated any even number of times. A constraint was there that you need to find that number in a single pass using constant memory. {assume all are positive numbers}.
i acheived this easily by making this function

```
  private static int nonRepeatingElement(int[] set) 
  {
        int element = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++) 
        {
            element = (element ^ set[i]);
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    return element;
 }
```

and this is working fine.
Now just because of curiosity i thought to change the problem with similar constraints.
**Problem1**
I thought of a set that now contains elements which can occur any odd number of time except one element which occures even no of time. `for example`  {2,5,7,5,7,1,2,7,1,5,2}
Now consereding the logic that XNOR gives 0 for every odd occurence of 1 i changed the code a little like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++) 
            {
                element = (element ^ set[i]);
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        return ~element;
```

but this didn't work.
**Problem2**
if i take elements in the set like {2,5,7,5,7,1,2,7,5,2} thinking XNORing will make every thrice occurence of number to 0 and XNORing with 1(single occurrence) to  0 will flip the bits of 1.So final result can be acheived if  i flip(~) the bits of what I'm gettting from XNOR operation.But this also doesnt work.
I know why this semantics is going wrong as it is bitwise operation not logical.But if xoring can be used for finding odd occurance of a number Isn't there any way with XNOR for finding even occurrent of a number?
I'm not sure about the feasibility of this problem I'm asking just out of curiosity so forgive my ignorance if it's irrelevent in any context.

Comment: XNOR would be this `~(element ^ set[i]);` but now the `~` is after the loop.

Comment: here actually there are multiple operands(i/p) on which i have to apply XNOR operation.I cannot cascade o/p of 2 i/p xnor operation for finding 3 i/p XNOR operation.that's why first i'm xoring all i/p's then using ~, for passing the final XNORed value to the calling function.

Comment: I think you can't do that with constant memory for numbers of any size. With even repetitions you are 'doing something' and then 'undoing it' but that makes no sense with odd repetitions. You need to keep more information about the numbers you found before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XOR` and `XNOR` are commutative. This means that any re-ordering of the sequence will always yield the same result.

You already know that `a ^ a` is zero. That's how the single number abstraction works: `a ^ b ^ a` equals `a ^ a ^ b` which equals `0 ^ b` which is `b`.

But `a XNOR a` is also **not** a function of `a`. It's simply a whole load of 1 bits. Therefore you can't recover the value of `a` using `a XNOR a` and so your approach will not work.

Comment: So is there any other approach for achieving the result in this scenario?

Comment: Not with Boolean operations and O(N) traversal, no. Why not try and *prove* that?